# Getting lua error when I'm calling a bound c++ class function twice?

Tags: c++, c, lua

I found this blog post about how to bind c++ classes to lua: http://loadcode.blogspot.com/2007/02/wrapping-c-classes-in-lua.html

But it's not working straight out of the box.
I've tweaked the function to my own and instead of a Sprite class I'm using a NPC class.
I changed the function `setSpeed` to my own called `NpcSetPosition(lua_State *L)` which will be     called everytime I call the following in lua:

```
local npc = Npc:New()
npc:SetPosition(5,5)
```

(the npc:SetPosition function)

Now what's interesting is how I call the `checkSprite` inside the `NpcSetPosition` and if I do so once, the lua script will run all fine. But if I do it twice(I call  `npc:SetPosition(5,5)` twice) I get the following error message:

```
Lua Compile Error: script.lua:10: bad argument #1-1 to: 'SetPosition' (table expected, got userdata)
```

Which means I can't set the position for the npc twice which is crap.
Do you know what's going wrong?
Does it have to do with the lua stack? 
Thanks.

Comment: "I've tweaked the function to my own" Could you show us the tweaked version?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/3xMpCPG9

Comment: I meant for you to put it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are incorrectly managing your stack.

Are you doing lua_settop( 0 ); or similar in your SetPosition function?
If your managing your stack correctly then this error will disappear.